# Proof of uniqueness to the right

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

There is a function $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given. This function is non-increasing, so that we have:
$$\forall\,{x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}},\; x_1< x_2 \implies f(t, x_1) - f(t, x_2) \ge 0.$$
There is also a differential equation given with the initial condition:
$$\begin{cases} x'=f(t,x)\\x(t_0) = x_0.\end{cases}$$
Let's consider two solutions of the equation above: $\phi_1, \phi_2$.
To show uniqueness, it should be proved that $\phi_1 \equiv\phi_2$.

This is my attempt:
assume $\phi_1 \not\equiv \phi_2$ and $\phi_1 < \phi_2$.
Because both $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are solutions I can write:
$$\begin{cases} \phi_1'=f(t,\phi_1)\\\phi(t_0) = x_0\end{cases}$$
and also
$$\begin{cases} \phi_2'=f(t,\phi_2)\\\phi_2(t_0) = x_0.\end{cases}$$
Now I can consider this 
$$\phi_1' - \phi_2' = f(t,\phi_1) - f(t,\phi_2) \ge 0,$$
thus
$$\phi_1' \ge \phi_2'.$$
By integrating both sides of the equation above I do get
$$\phi_1 - \phi_2 \ge C.$$
However that doesn't lead me to anything useful.

I was trying to show that $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ differ by at most a constant and then use [Picard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem). Unfortunately my attempt failed. I would appreciate any hints or tips.

Comment: Just because $\phi_1\not=\phi_2$ doesn't mean $\phi_1<\phi_2$. That is an unnecessarily strict assumption.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Thanks. So how can we use the fact that $f$ is non-increasing?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite buy the conclusion. Are you sure there aren't any other assumptions? Particularly about $f?$

Comment: @AdrianKeister We also know that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: The solution to this one is beyond me. You could try Coddington and Levinson, as well as looking at the standard existence and uniqueness theorems of Peano, Caratheodory, Okamura, and Moyer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get
$$
\frac{d}{dt}[ϕ_1(t)-ϕ_2(t)]^2=2[ϕ_1(t)-ϕ_2(t)][f(t,ϕ_1(t))-f(t,ϕ_2(t))]\le 0
$$
by the non-increasing assumption. Thus
$$
[ϕ_1(t)-ϕ_2(t)]^2\le[ϕ_1(t_0)-ϕ_2(t_0)]^2~\text{ for }~ t>t_0
$$
with the obvious consequence.

Comment: Why did you consider $\frac{d}{dt}[\phi_1(t) - \phi_2(t)]^2$

Comment: Because the monotonicity condition can be written as $\forall x_1,x_2:\;(x_1-x_2)(f(t,x_1)-f(t,x_2))\le 0$. Then recognize that on solutions the second factor is the derivative of the first.

Comment: So I understand that we do use the assumption: $\phi_1(t) < \phi_2(t)$? And why do we use $\phi_1(0), \phi_2(0)$?

Comment: No, you use that a square of real numbers is never negative, and that $ϕ_1(0)=ϕ_2(0)$.

Comment: So if we don't use the assumption that $\phi_1(t) < \phi_2(t)$ so how can we justify that $[\phi_1(t) - \phi_2(t)][f(t, \phi_1(t)) - f(t, \phi_2(t))]$. We don't know whether $[\phi_1(t) - \phi_2(t)]$ is negative or positive. By $\phi_1(0)$ you mean $\phi_1(t_0)$?

Comment: Yes to $t_0$ instead of $0$. The situation is symmetric, if the solutions are different then one at one point will be larger than the other. Which is not possible if the square of their difference is zero.

Comment: Now things are much clearer! Thank you. I hope it is the last question - how did you get from $\frac{d}{dt}[\phi_1(t) - \phi_2(t)]^2 \le 0$ to $[\phi_1(t) - \phi_2(t)]^2 \le 0 = [\phi_1(t_0) - \phi_2(t_0)]$?

Comment: Just integrate from $t_0$ to $t$. A non-positive integrand gives a non-positive integral.

Comment: Thank you for your time! Now I understand your solution :)